# How to delete a user from SonarQube and re-activate?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

In our SonarQube instance we have recently enabled LDAP authentication. Prior to LDAP integration the users were manually created. It so happened some of the users were created using the same LDAP user ID and custom password.

Now when LDAP is integrated we want all users use the LDAP ID/pass instead of previously manually created ID/password. SonarQube login works with manually created password rather than LDAP password. So how do remove the manually created users and only activate the LDAP users?

PS: I dont see the option to delete but only to de-activate

[image]

Comment: As an administrator you can remove users (Administration > Security > Users)

Comment: I can de-activate but not remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As replied by Jeroen Heier in comments, removing users from Administration > Security > Users will allow you to reuse the login of the removed user with an LDAP account.

If it's not the case, please describe what you're doing.

Comment: I dont see the option of delete but I see de-activate. Refer to update picture above in my question.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Deletion is not possible, only de-activation is possible but still you can safely use the login of a disable user in LDAP

Comment: The user is still available in the "users" table. I want to delete a user permanently, as if it had never existed. It was a test user, deleting records from a DB really shouldn't be so hard. (Update: I deleted it with a delete query with direct db access. I think it is **BAAAD**)

Comment: Btw, did you ever thought on to do something with that mess of unparametrized generics in your code?

Comment: Don't worry, SQ is f*g good! In its functionality. I understand that in the case of a mainly opensource software it can't be perfect in every sense. Of course I won't ever criticize you until I didn't committed some patch to your pretty work! :-)

Comment: Nice to see this question again, as I want to delete a user again :-) Please do something, not being able to delete a user seems to me a real problem.

Comment: There's a JIRA ticket to allow deleting a user : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7243. Do not hesitate to vote for it !

Answer (score 0):

While I'm concerned with the deletion of an account...  why can't you re-activate a user if you de-activated them through the UI.  This is incredibly painful if a user was accidentally deactivated.